# PHP Trying to solve RAM issue but webgrind wont display milliseconds

Tags: php, memory, xdebug, webgrid

I'm getting the following error:

```
    Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in /var/www/AutoVerify3/php/xml2array.php on line 66
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory     Function          Location
1   0.0000  724976      {main}( )       ../index.php:0
2   1.4077  3277160     xml2array( )    ../index.php:57
3   1.9923  134175016   array_keys ( )  ../xml2array.php:66
```

What my script is doing is storing a large XML (2MB+) in an associative array.  I have Xdebug setup and webgrind to determine what exactly is consuming all my RAM but the results from webgrind aren't expected:

-First the bar at the top (with the different colors showing the distribution) is tiny - it doesn't take up the whole grid that is displayed:

```
|(BAR)|    |    |    |    |    |    |
```

-Second webgrind doesn't tell me how many milliseconds the script ran for, so instead of:

> 34 different functions called in 100 milliseconds (1 runs, 34 shown)
>   It says:
>
> 34 different functions called in milliseconds ( runs, 34 shown)
>   -Third, the chart doesn't display any other types of functions other than internal and include - this just might be because the script isn't allowed to get that far.

Any help on webgrind or the mem issue is much appreciated.

Edit Here is the code from xml2array - it's a function I borrowed from somewhere a while back:

```
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'tag') {
if(!$contents) return array();

if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) {
    //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!";
    return array();
}

//Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work
$parser = xml_parser_create('');
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); # http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values);
xml_parser_free($parser);

if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm...

//Initializations
$xml_array = array();
$parents = array();
$opened_tags = array();
$arr = array();

$current = &$xml_array; //Refference

//Go through the tags.
$repeated_tag_index = array();//Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array
foreach($xml_values as $data) {
    unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble

    //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope
    // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array).
    extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler.

    $result = array();
    $attributes_data = array();

    if(isset($value)) {
        if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value;
        else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode
    }

    //Set the attributes too.
    if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) {
        foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) {
            if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val;
            else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr'
        }
    }

    //See tag status and do the needed.
    if($type == "open") {//The starting of the tag '<tag>'
        $parent[$level-1] = &$current;
        if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag
            $current[$tag] = $result;
            if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;

            $current = &$current[$tag];

        } else { //There was another element with the same tag name

            if(isset($current[$tag][0])) {//If there is a 0th element it is already an array
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;
            } else {//This section will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2;

                if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well
                    $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                    unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                }

            }
            $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1;
            $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index];
        }

    } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />'
        //See if the key is already taken.
        if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key
            $current[$tag] = $result;
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
            if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;

        } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array)
            if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) {//If it is already an array...

                // ...push the new element into that array.
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;

                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) {
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                }
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;

            } else { //If it is not an array...
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) {
                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well

                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                        unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                    }

                    if($attributes_data) {
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                    }
                }
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken
            }
        }

    } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag '</tag>'
        $current = &$parent[$level-1];
    }
}

return($xml_array);
```

}

Comment: Are you using SimpleXML? And if so, what version of PHP?

Comment: @AlexHowansky - No, XML parser. PHP v5.3.6

Comment: @horatio - I added the code, here is the line: `if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag`

Comment: @jreed121:  any reason not to increase the php memory limit further to see if can complete?

Comment: @wallyk - I considered it but I wanted to see if this issue was caused by something else first. 16MB is a decent amount considering that the script only runs for a second or two before it throws the error - there is a lot of heavy lifting to be done after the xml is converted to an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear that `array_keys` is the culprit here. If I read it correctly, you are requesting an array of data that have the key `$current`. `array_keys` returns an array of indices which match that criteria, and your information shows that the returned array is 128MB in size: so there are a lot of items with the same key.

This is the only `array_keys` call in the code and it is on the line you mention. See if you can figure out a method to replace this call: one which does not replicate or copy information. Sometimes one can use `isset` instead of `in_array` etc.